What are the advantages and disadvantages of keeping Git branches, after you have merged?
I have recently moved projects at work and have come across a developer who stands by keeping all Git branches, even after the work which has been associated with the branch has been completed and merged into the master/main branch.
In my old project, as soon as the work was done and the branch had been merged we would delete the branch, making for a much cleaner looking repository with only active branches present.
The new repo looks horrendous to me, with branches that have not been worked on in months and are 900+ commits behind.
What are the advantages and disadvantages of keeping these branches alive for so long?

What is said coworker's rationale behind their "keep all branches" policy? Make them explicitly formulate it, and unless they come up with good reasons, treat it as cargo cult programming.

There’s no point if the commits are merged unless they want to keep the name. And if they want to keep the name they can move them to another ref so that you don’t have hundreds of branches to look through. As for keeping branches that did not get merged: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/450379/what-do-you-do-with-branches-youve-abandoned

This repo has 564 branches which I always found interesting

@Guildenstern 4404 branches on the repo I'm working on at the moment. Saying that I can relate to OP is an understatement.

My work repo only has 926 branches on the remote. We’re too good at closing the merged branches in Bitbucket.

I'm going to push back against the presuppositions of the question. You (the OP) seem to think it makes a difference to the topology of the history whether branches are kept or deleted after merging. It doesn't. It makes no difference to the topology whether branches are kept or deleted after merging.
A branch is merely a name attached to one commit. That commit is still there after merging, whether the name is thrown away or not. Example with the branch name kept:
A -- B -- C -- M -- D (main)
 \           /
  X -- Y -- Z (feature)

Example without the branch name kept:
A -- B -- C -- M -- D (main)
 \           /
  X -- Y -- Z

As you can see, the only difference between the two topologies is whether commit Z has the branch name feature attached to it. The commit Z and its ancestors are reachable from main, because M has Z as one of its parents, and so the topologies are identical.
What does make a difference to the topology is whether you merge the feature branches or not. In the illustrations above, feature was merged into main, which means that a merge commit was created on main (designated as M). But most pull request / merge request implementations provide alternate ways of disposing of a feature branch. For example, GitHub lets you do something called a "squash":
A -- B -- C -- M -- D (main)
 \           
  X -- Y -- Z (feature)

Here, M is not a merge commit; it is just a commit. Therefore the tip of feature, namely Z, is not reachable from main. Therefore it does make a difference whether you keep the name feature, because if you delete it, Z will no longer be reachable and it and its unreachable ancestors will eventually be deleted as well:
A -- B -- C -- M -- D (main)
 \           
  X -- Y -- Z

[Later:]
A -- B -- C -- M -- D (main)

Now, some people may think of that as "cleaner". But others, including me, think of it as "horrible", because it obscures history. M no longer has any relationship to the past commits that generated it. Therefore I think it is better to make true merge commits, as in my earlier example, but delete the feature branch names, as they add nothing to the story. You may not like the resulting elaborate topology, but the topology represents the true history of what happened, and that can be important in tracking down where a bug came from and so forth.

Also it's important to remember that what you see of the topology depends on what you ask for. There are a lot of ways of saying git log! They exist for a reason; they are there to help you "simplify" the history with respect to the information you're looking for. You do not have to look at the total graph of the entire topology if you don't want to.

As you already mentioned the most obvious disadvantage is that the complexity increases when branches are kept. You will not be easily able to identify which branches contain any relevant changes.
An advantage of keeping the branches is that you can view prior versions or snapshots of the repository by looking a branch that was used in the past. This way you may be able to view a feature before it was merged into other branches (such as main), which can help to debug or find reasons for certain behavior.

Could the same thing not be done with the commit history? Provided the commit messages are meaningful and full of detail, which is a requirement of the project.

Of course. But some people may prefer to switch branches and see what was going on there.

I wouldn't call this an advantage. You can simply checkout the 2nd parent of the merge commit if you want to be at the same state the feature branch was in before it was merged. In fact, checking out the commit is guaranteed to be correct, whereas checking out the branch is not, since it could have been updated after the merge if someone pushed more commits to that branch name.

Of course you can but people may still prefer to use the UI of their system to switch between different states of the repository.
